# AngularJs UnitTesting Jasmine + kamra + Angular Mock Create a UnitTest for getModules Function

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

This is my dashboardService, and I would like to create Unit Test for getModules

================================================================================

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    var __Name = "dashboardService";    
    var __Path = "components/dashboard";     

    angular
    .module(window.__env.appName,[])
        .factory(__Name, serviceFunc);

  serviceFunc.$inject = ['$cookies','$http'];

  function serviceFunc($cookies,$http) {      
      return {
                      getmodules: function (cb) {
                          $http({
                              method: 'GET',
                              url:'/home/modulesInfo'

                          }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                              cb(true, response);
                          }, function errorCallback(response) {
                              cb(false, response)
                          });
                      }

            }   
    }  

})(window.angular);
```

====================================================================

## the following is my spec file(dashboardService.spec.js)

```
'use strict';
describe('getmodules', function () {
    beforeEach(function () { module('ngMockE2E'); });
    var service, httpBackend, defaultAlertFactory;
    beforeEach(function () {
        debugger;
        module('myApp');
        module(function ($provide) {
            var dashboardService = {
                getMegetmodules: function () {
                    // mocked method
                    return ['david', 'James', 'Sam'];
                }
            };

            $provide.service('defaultAlertFactoryA', dashboardService);
        });
        angular.mock.inject(function ($injector) {
            service = $injector.get('defaultAlertFactoryA');
            httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

        });

    });

    //describe('getmodules', function () {
    it("should return a list of getmodules", inject(function () {
        debugger;
        httpBackend.expectGET('/Home/modulesInfo').respond(['david', 'James', 'Sam']);
        service.getmodules(function (result) {
            expect(result).toEqual(["david", "James", "Sam"]);
        });
        httpBackend.flush();
    }))
    //})
```

## });

Thanks!

Comment: Here is the error message:::::::::getmodules should return a list of getmodules
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20Object
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a typo, your dashboardService is defining a function called getMegetmodules, and in your test function you're calling to service.getmodules, you should do something like:

```
module(function ($provide) {
    var dashboardService = {
        getModules: function () {
            // mocked method
            return ['david', 'James', 'Sam'];
        }
    };

    $provide.service('defaultAlertFactoryA', dashboardService);
});
```

And in your test function:

```
it("should return a list of getmodules", inject(function () {
    debugger;
    httpBackend.expectGET('/Home/modulesInfo').respond(['david', 'James', 'Sam']);
    service.getModules(function (result) {
        expect(result).toEqual(["david", "James", "Sam"]);
    });
    httpBackend.flush();
}));
```

Hope that help!
pd: I think you don't need that httpBackend.flush() there

Comment: Could you create a plunker ?